# Append text with object values

Tags: arrays, json

I am getting object as:

```
  {  
   Id:3233,
   Topics:"topic",
   TopicId:101,
   Alreadyactiontaken:null,
   …
}
```

But i need json format as below to pass on the api:

```
{  
   "Data":[  
      {  
         "Id":477,
         Topics:"topic",
         TopicId:101,
         Alreadyactiontaken:null,

      }
   ]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Right now, this reads like a "code this for me" request, which is off-topic. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: *"I am getting json as"* That's not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you just need to create such an object:

```
let value = {Id: 3233, Topics: "topic", TopicId: 101, Alreadyactiontaken: null, …}
let apiValue = { Data: [value] }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can push your json data into array and assign a key for this. Like following in javascript.

```js
var array = [];
var json = {Id: 3233, Topics: "topic", TopicId: 101, Alreadyactiontaken: null};
array.push(json);
var newdata = {};
newdata.data = array;
console.log(newdata);
```